# Installing Python wrapper for METIS: Cannot locate METIS_DLL shared library

Tags: macos, python, environment-variables

I am planning to use Metis for drawing some networks and graphs using Python 2.7. I downloaded Metis from [here](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/download). I compiled and installed the source code without any problems. For installing the Python wrapper, I followed the instructions given [here](http://metis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but when I run the easy_install command like:

```
$ easy_install metis
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Could not locate METIS dll. Please set the METIS_DLL environment variable to its full path.
```

From the second link above, I understand that I have to specify the full path to some 'METIS shared library' file in the METIS_DLL environment variable. But I don't know what the file is called and where it is located or how I should specify the path in an environment variable.

According to my research on Google, I found out that the file might be called 'libmetis.so' but I don't have any file of that name in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib` or `/opt`. Could someone give me a clue on this?

I am working on Mac OS X 10.6.8, with Python 2.7.3.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add "shared=1" to your config options when building Metis from source so it builds a shared library instead of a static one.

```
make config shared=1
make install
```

Then, set up your METIS_DLL environment variable:

```
export METIS_DLL=/usr/local/lib/libmetis.dylib
```

Source: http://metis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/metis.html

Comment: I was trying on linux and got the same error while importing metis in python. The fix was that I ran `export METIS_DLL=/usr/local/lib/libmetis.so` instead of dylib extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the path `../metis-5.1.0/build/Linux-x86_64/libmetis/libmetis.so`, as Installer build code in its own directory.
If the file exists, then write the path to variable METIS_DLL:

```
# specify your full path
export METIS_DLL=../metis-5.1.0/build/Linux-x86_64/libmetis/libmetis.so
```

See issue https://github.com/guglielmosanchini/ClustViz/issues/1